# Spinner text size does not change?

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, android-spinner

I could not change spinner's textsize or colour with the code below:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    style="@style/submitspinner"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:entries="@array/a_code"
    android:prompt="@string/p_code" />
```

style:

```
<style name="submitspinner" parent="@android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/pt</item> 
</style>
```

It looks same, how can I increase textsize and change colour of the spinner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you should do for custom Spinners is create a single XML that will act as your template for the string in the Spinner, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/standard_spinner_format"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="@dimen/pt"
   android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
```

Then when you create your Spinner adapter in java do the following:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), 
          R.array.my_spinner_array, R.layout.custom_xml_spinner_layout); //change the last argument here to your xml above.
    typeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: The OP is using static entries via `android:entries` to populate his Spinner. There's a way to style the Spinners without setting the adapter via code. I added an answer to show how.

Answer (score 41):

### Via XML Only

*Just to help others in case they are statically setting their Spinner entries in XML.*

The above answers work if you're creating your *Spinner* via code but if you're setting your *Spinner* entries via XML, i.e. using `android:entries`, then you can adjust the text size and other attributes with the following two theme settings:

#### In your res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- For the resting Spinner style -->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerItemStyle
        </item> 

        <!-- For each individual Spinner list item once clicked on -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
        </item>

    </style>

    <style name="spinnerItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: This is a good info [+1] .... Also adding  <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner"> for example will make customizations easier

Comment: +1 for addressing styles.xml. I find most developer tend to shoot for a programmatic solution and ignore the less appreciated aspects of the Android framework.

Comment: How can I use and apply these styles on my spinner? it doesn't work with me.

Comment: @Tareq What SDK version are you on (e.g. 4.0.3)?

Comment: For AppCompat theme just remove `android:` like this `<item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>`

Answer (score 1):

customize your spinner

here is a good tutorial i once used

http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.be/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html

it has everything u need.

also in your 'style' u have:

```
<item name="android:layout_margin">10sp</item>
```

change it to 10dp

sp = text size

here u can find more about units to measure

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_5"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_base" />

 adapter?.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text)
spSourceAccount.adapter = adapter
```