# Replacing the spinner textbox with a custom textbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I was just wondering if it's possible to replace a spinner textbox (default) as shown in the image below:
[image: default textbox]

with a custom textbox ( like an arrow at the end and nothing behind the selectable textbox as shown:
[image: custom textbox]

If it's possible how do I go about it? How do I replace

Comment: I don't know about the arrow but for text size, color, etc., see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693941/spinner-text-size-does-not-change/16694058#16694058)

Comment: just add background to that spinner