# Android: set custom text color in spinner dropdown

Tags: android, colors, spinner, customization, android-version

I have custom ArrayAdapter for spinners and need to change text color of items in dropdown. Code seems to be ok, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
public class CustomRadioArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>  {

    public CustomRadioArrayAdapter(Context context, T[] data) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        this.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    public CustomRadioArrayAdapter(Context context, List<T> data) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        this.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (view != null && view instanceof CheckedTextView) {
            ((CheckedTextView) view).setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.radio);
            ((CheckedTextView) view).setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 255));
        }
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinback);
        return view;
    }    
}
```

**UPD**
I figured out that this code is not working on Android 4.0.4 on Lenovo, while on Android 4.0.3 HTC everything is displayed the right way.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693941/spinner-text-size-does-not-change/16694058#16694058) on how to customize a spinner.

Comment: So only change the color when the list is expanded?

Comment: Oh.. not sure about that one. You may want to specify that more clearly in your question

Comment: @TronicZomB I thought saying "dropdown" was clear enough. Anyway, see my updates, may be you have any idea.

Comment: I think what you will have to do is create a custom layout for the `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. Though I don't know how to.